# SSRS Server Aggregates with SQL Server Connection Type

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

In BOL it states that the SQL Server Connection type supports server aggregates here;

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220582(v=sql.105).aspx

However other than this one mention I cant find a single example of how to use server aggregates with a SQL Server Connection type (All examples I have seen are about SSAS).

For a number of reports it would be really useful to be able to pre-calculate aggregates (for performance reasons or where the aggregate is more complicated than the normal sum, avg etc..)

So, Is it possible to use server aggregates in this way and if so how?

Thanks

Comment: I'd guess they are talking about SSAS aggregates.  Other than that, I think you're left with using GROUP BY in a Text Connection Type, or doing your aggregation in a Stored Procedure and getting it via the Stored Procedure Connection Type.

Comment: Yeah I saw that but it seemed to imply that you could use it in sql server. I'm fine using SQL to calculate the aggregate the issue is getting SSRS to recognize it as a subtotal so you can use the aggregate function.